# Getting custom form to work in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, schema

I built a custom new form for a page and in the schema file I did the following:

```
<Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
```

So it looks for my custom form, it works fine for new clients I create but ones already in the system still point to the standard new form

```
<Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
```

So I've tried to create an upgrade rule to get the older ones to look at the custom form by doing this:

```
var list = web.TryGetList("Client Programs");
list.DefaultNewFormUrl = "NewForm.aspx";
list.Update();
```

But I have a feeling this won't do anything, is there some way to point the old data to the new custom form through the site settings page, or what would I need to add/change in the upgrade rule to get this working?

**Update**

I should also mention that in the properties for the form I have changed it to look in the hive for the form and made it an elementfile.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Existing items are edited by the EditForm.aspx, not from the newform.aspx

You have to duplicate newform.aspx and name it editform.aspx (a displayform.aspx could be created to).

```
<Forms>
  <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="features\$SharePoint.Feature.DeploymentPath$\YourProject\CustomDisplay.aspx" UseLegacyForm="True" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="features\$SharePoint.Feature.DeploymentPath$\YourProject\CustomEdit.aspx" UseLegacyForm="True" WebPartZoneID="Main"  />
  <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="features\$SharePoint.Feature.DeploymentPath$\YourProject\CustomNew.aspx" UseLegacyForm="True" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
</Forms>
```

For each form,each SharePoint form field have to be tagged with the correct control mode

New Form :

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" ID="field_YourFieldName" ControlMode="New" FieldName="YourFieldName" />
```

Edit Form :

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" ID="field_YourFieldName" ControlMode="Edit"                                                    FieldName="YourFieldName" />
```

Display Form :

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" ID="field_YourFieldName" ControlMode="Display"                                                        FieldName="YourFieldName" />
```

Comment: I may not have worded my question correctly, it's not that I'm trying to edit something, it's when I'm trying to add a new record. It displays the custom newform when I do it with new clients, but with the pre-existing clients it still displays the old new form.